# Docker image verification

Tags: docker, azure-container-service

I have created a dotnet core application ,dockerized and pushed it to the azure container registry using Azure pipeline.
If I check the repository, I can see tar.gzip files and json file references in the images created.
How to verify if I have the created the image without any issues? Is there a way to troubleshoot the images created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On both your local environment and on the Azure registry you can look/compare the digests

```
docker images --digests
```

You can directly get the digest ID from the image (this is the RepoDigests attribute)

```
docker inspect --format='{{index .RepoDigests 0}}' {IMAGE_NAME}
```

If you want to see all details about the image

```
docker inspect {IMAGE_NAME}
```

The `inspect` command displays a detailed summary of the image, including the digest above and the layers composing the image